# How to bring a child window to the front in a c# winform application?

Tags: c#, winforms

When I click on a button in the main form, I want another form to open within the main form. This works so far with the following code:

```
private void btnOpenChildForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    ChildForm Form = new ChildForm();
    this.IsMdiContainer = true;
    Form.MdiParent = this;

    Form.Show();
}
```

Problem:

The buttons and other controls of the main form are still visible in the child form. I tried it with `Form.BringToFront()`, but it did not work neither.

**Update**

This is what worked so far for me, after deciding to change the GUI design. I took a ToolStripMenuItem instead of the buttons I had before.

A global variable(I think I have to improve that)

```
    ChildForm frmChildForm;
```

The click method:

```
    private void frmChildFormToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                if (frmChildForm  == null || frmChildForm .IsDisposed == true)
                {
                    frmChildForm  = new ChildForm();

                }

                this.IsMdiContainer = true;
                frmChildForm.MdiParent = this;
                frmChildForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                frmChildForm.Show();

            }
```

Comment: Ideally the intention of MDI form is to serve as a container for other child forms and should not have button controls. So if you want to do that would recommend to re-design to have a menu option to open another form OR do with SDI form.

Comment: Seems to be the right way. I tried `Form.BringToFront()` and `Form.Focus()`. That didn't work. Can I just copy the button and content declarations from the mainform.designer.cs into the new childform.designer.cs. Will that work? Because I have a dozen of controls there in the main form.

Comment: I have pasted code. Let me know if it serves your purpose. If i understand correctly you need not have a MDI here. if the new form is smaller it will center inside your parent form.

Comment: Thx, that works flawless, but indeed I need to go the MDI way. Is there a way to change the main window into a child window, without rebuilding the GUI from hand?

Comment: Change MDI form property "IsMDIContainer=True" to False. Currently it will be set to true and that is what is making it an MDI container. And use the code i have written. You will not need to rebuild the UI. Let me know if that solves your issue.

Comment: Tried it. That works, but solves not the problem I have. I can still move the child window out of the main window. But is has to stay within the main window.

Answer (score 2):

I Think , you need to use `Focus()` method for that.

```
private void btnOpenChildForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChildForm Form = new ChildFrom();
    this.IsMdiContainer = true;
    Form.MdiParent = this;
    Form.Show();
    Form.focus();
}
```

Comment: This won't help. If you place a button on MDI form (which ideally you shouldn't)  it will show up above your child form.

Comment: Hey I referred many sites thet you can't use any controls on MDI form. Still you need to do so means, you have to hide the button after clicked and you have to show the button after MDI form activated.

Answer (score 1):

look to this example it might solve your problem:
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/309232/Csharp-net-How-to-bring-a-MDI-child-form-to-the-fr

Answer (score 1):

Like i said Ideally the MDI should only have the Menu control and Status Bar and that would be the intention of a MDI. To just act as a container for other forms nothing else.

So if you just want a child form to open up on top of your parentform do this (SDI way).

```
private void btnOpenChildForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    //if you just want the form to show on top do not make the MDI

    ChildForm Form = new ChildForm();
    Form.Show();
    Form.Owner=this;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7571/Creating-MDI-application-using-C-Walkthrough :

```
ChildForm Form = ChildForm.GetChildInstance();
Form.MdiParent = this;
Form.Show();
Form.BringToFront();
```